# google anylatics not distinct the android | ios platform. Its display active mobiles users with mobile brawser too

Tags: google-analytics, ionic2, firebase-analytics

I am using ionic 2 for google analytics. but in google section it display mobile browser user too as an active user. I want each section (web,ios,android) individually.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to assign a custom dimension to the tracker based on the platform, for example (custom dimension with index 1 in Google Analytics):

```
if(this.platform.is('android') {
    window.ga.addCustomDimension(1, 'android')
}
if(this.platform.is('ios') {
    window.ga.addCustomDimension(1, 'ios')
}
```

Then you can see that value in Analytics reports.